wwan cellular connection etc issues
I have an X1 carbon gen 5 (Ubuntu 24.04.1) which I upgraded recently w/ a wwan card & the antennae. I don't get the broadband connection to work. I'm stuck at at the point were Ubuntu doesn't recognize the SIM card. It did so before, some days ago. I tried it with 2 different cards, both were at least recognized
mmcli --modem=0 tells me this:
Status   |             state: failed
|     failed reason: sim-missing
|       power state: low
Any ideas how what to do?
Warmly
